# Retrieve contact's name with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am trying to access my Google Contacts via the API. (Apache Shindig, OAuth2).
I am able to retrieve details from contacts like email, phoneNumber, postalAddress. However, it says that the name of all contacts is null (but they do have names).

I am doing it like this:

```
        if (entry.gd$email) {
          var valueNode = document.createTextNode(entry.gd$email[0].address);
          divElement.appendChild(valueNode);
          divElement.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
        if (entry.gd$phoneNumber) {
          var valueNode = document.createTextNode(entry.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t);
          divElement.appendChild(valueNode);
          divElement.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
        if (entry.gd$postalAddress) {
          var valueNode = document.createTextNode(entry.gd$postalAddress[0].$t);
          divElement.appendChild(valueNode);
        }
```

It works smoothly, I get all the information I need. However, `if (entry.gd$name)` says that the name is null, if all my contact have names.
Am I using a wrong command?

Comment: I've got it:
For retrieving the name, entry.atom$title works fine.
It seems a bit strange to me, and I think it only works for reading the name (which is enough for me at the moment).
If someone knows some details about it, go on :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `entry.gd$fullName`

Title will usually do it too, not always for some reason.

If that doesn't work, try to spit out the XML result so you see which field is holding that contact's name.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3